# Why does Mathematica "sleep" when I don't work at computer?

Tags: evaluation, numerics

I started using Mathematica few days ago. I'm running this code:

```
r1 = {0, 500, 0};
r2 = {0, 0, 0};
r3 = {0, 250, 1000};
v1 = {20, 20, 0};
v2 = {-20, -20, -0};
v3 = {0, 0, 0};
m1 = 5000000000000000;
m2 = 5000000000000000;
m3 = 5000000000000000;

G = 6.674*10^(-11);

l1 = {};
l2 = {};
l3 = {};

dT = 0.001;

For[i = 0, i < 2000001, i++,


  If[Mod[i, 100] == 0, l1 = Append[l1, r1]; l2 = Append[l2, r2]; 
   l3 = Append[l3, r3]; Print[i/2000000]];

  force12 = (G/Norm[r2 - r1]^3)*(r2 - r1);
  force13 = (G/Norm[r3 - r1]^3)*(r3 - r1);
  force23 = (G/Norm[r3 - r2]^3)*(r3 - r2);

  a1 = force12*m2 + force13*m3;
  a2 = -force12*m1 + force23*m3;
  a3 = -force13*m1 - force23*m3;

  f1[t_] := r1 + v1*t + a1*t^2/2;
  f2[t_] := r2 + v2*t + a2*t^2/2;
  f3[t_] := r3 + v3*t + a3*t^2/2;

  r1 = N[f1[dT], 12];
  r2 = N[f2[dT], 12];
  r3 = N[f3[dT], 12];

  v1 = N[f1'[dT], 12];
  v2 = N[f2'[dT], 12];
  v3 = N[f3'[dT], 12];
  ListPointPlot3D[{l1, l2, l3}]

  ];

ListPointPlot3D[{l1, l2, l3}]
TableForm[l1];
Export["sh01.tsv", l1];
TableForm[l1];
Export["sh02.tsv", l1];
TableForm[l1];
Export["sh03.tsv", l1];
```

Obviously this process take a lot of time.

Initially Mathematica works, but after some minutes of computer inactivity (I don't use computer) it stops running: I observe that CPU isn't working and there isn't any output on notebook. When I click on notebook Mathematica restarts computation, my CPU work at 30% and code restarts to print the state of work (Print[i/2000000]).

I'm using Mathematica 10 on Windows 7, I had the some problem with Mathematica 10 on Windows 8.

What I have to do for keeping Mathematica running?

P.S.: I don't know if my problem is with Mathematica or with my computer setting, however I tried this work on two computers and I observed the some thing.

Comment: This is really an extraordinary claim, which is probably why your question was downvoted. People are probably not going to run your time-consuming code to try to observe a problem that they most likely don't believe exists, so could you please provide some concrete and convincing evidence for what you observe as part of the question? Specifically, why should we believe it is a problem with *Mathematica*, rather than with your computer?

Comment: And which version of *Mathematica*, and which operating system, are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 10, on windows 7 and 8

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but have you considered removing the `ListPointPlot3D` from the loop? Why compute 2 million graphics expressions which you never display?

Comment: I do observe the same behavior (10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 x86-64).

Comment: Really really thank's Simon Woods! I forgot that row from a previous code. You didn't solve my problem but saved a lot of my time ;)

Comment: With that `ListPointPlot3D` removed, this code can be evaluated in about 6 mins without problem.

Comment: And I think you meant to `Export` `l1`,`l2`,`l3`, not three`l1`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing the integration yourself, why not have Mathematica do it for you?

```
g = 6.674*^-11;
dt = 0.001;
tStop = 2000;

soln = First@NDSolve[{
    x1''[t] == 
     g (m2/Norm[x2[t] - x1[t]]^3 (x2[t] - x1[t]) + 
        m3/Norm[x3[t] - x1[t]]^3 (x3[t] - x1[t])), 
    x2''[t] == 
     g (m3/Norm[x3[t] - x2[t]]^3 (x3[t] - x2[t]) + 
        m1/Norm[x1[t] - x2[t]]^3 (x1[t] - x2[t])), 
    x3''[t] == 
     g (m1/Norm[x1[t] - x3[t]]^3 (x1[t] - x3[t]) + 
        m2/Norm[x2[t] - x3[t]]^3 (x2[t] - x3[t])),
    x1[0] == r1, x1'[0] == v1, x2[0] == r2, x2'[0] == v2, x3[0] == r3,
     x3'[0] == v3
    }, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, tStop}]

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[Through[{x1, x2, x3}[t]] /. soln], {t, 0, tStop}]
```

[image]

This takes under a second to evaluate.  You can still generate your tables:

```
Export["sh01.tsv", Table[x1[t] /. soln, {t, 0, tStop, dt}]]
```

But you may want to choose a larger timestep, since the table will currently have 2 million lines!

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know Mathematica can approssimate this kind of sistems! Do you know what algorithm it uses?

Comment: @Davide It can use a *lot* of different algorithms depending on the problem.  [Read the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html) to get an idea of `NDSolve`'s complexity.